# Can i somehow add millis to this code somewhere in the buttons or in the modes?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

i need to add millis in my code but i dont know exactly where should be ok to add millis or where is it acctually needed.Because i have used only delay till now can you help me and tell me where can millis be implemented in this piece of code.If it is possible to add millis somewhere in or after the button modes or switch case because it would be nicer if the modes changed properly because for now their changing either when the button is pressed normal or somtimes you need to pres the button twice to change to the next mode.I would apriciate all the help.

```
 const int BUTTON_SWITCH = 8;
    const int BUTTON_ALARM = 9;
    const int KNOB = A0;
    const int TEMP = A1;
    const int tempRES = 10000; // the resistance of the NTC at 25'C is 10k ohm
    const int NTC_MATERIAL_CONSTANT = 3950;
    const int RED_LED = 4;
    const int BUZZER = 3;
    int index = 1;
    double value;
    int state = 0;
    unsigned long time_now = 0;
    int period = 1000;
    char incomingOption;
    #include "Display.h"

    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      pinMode(BUTTON_SWITCH, INPUT_PULLUP);
      pinMode(BUTTON_ALARM, INPUT_PULLUP);
      pinMode(RED_LED, OUTPUT);
    }

    float get_temperature()
    {
      float temperature, resistance;
      int value;
      value = analogRead(TEMP);
      resistance   = (float)value * tempRES / (1024 - value); // Calculate resistance
      /* Calculate the temperature according to the following formula. */
      temperature  = 1 / (log(resistance / tempRES) / NTC_MATERIAL_CONSTANT + 1 / 298.15) - 273.15;
      return temperature;
    }
    void loop() {
      if (digitalRead(BUTTON_SWITCH) == LOW) {     // button for switching the 3 modes
        index = index + 1;
      }
      if (digitalRead(BUTTON_ALARM) == LOW) {      // button for the alarm
        displayAlarm();
      }
       if (Serial.available()) {
            // Read entire buffer up to newline character
            // Since on the C# side, serialPort1.WriteLine appends a newline character
            String respond = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
            if (respond == "RESET") {
                digitalWrite(RED_LED, LOW);
                digitalWrite(BUZZER, LOW);
            }
        }
      if (index > 3) {       // when the code is on the last mode press the button to turn back to the first mode
        index = 1;
      }

      get_temperature();
      float celcius;
      celcius = get_temperature();

      if(celcius<16 || celcius>27){        // if the temperature becomes less than 16 degrees or goes higher than 27 degrees turn on the alarm
        displayAlarm();
      }


      switch (index) {
        case 1: displayTime(); break;          // switch between the 3 different modes
        case 2: displayTemp(); break;
        case 3: displayAngle(); break;
      }

    }


    void displayTime() {
      float timer = Serial.parseFloat();   // take the current time from the c# application and display it on the arduino board
      Display.show(timer);
    }

    void displayTemp() {

      float celcius;
      celcius = get_temperature();      // mode for displaying the current temperature
      Display.show(celcius);
    }


    void displayAngle() {
      int value = analogRead(KNOB);  // read and save analog value from the potentionmeter 
      value = map(value, 0, 1023, 0, 30); // Map value 0-1023 to 0-30
      Display.show(value);
    }

    void displayAlarm() {
      Serial.println("Alarm");
      digitalWrite(RED_LED, HIGH);
      tone(BUZZER, 1500, 700);

    }
```

Comment: Can you prepare MRE as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish. What do you want to do with `millis()`? Oh, and please format your prose to make it understandable; the source code is really good formatted, for a beginner, thank you!

Comment: this is not C btw, changed your tags...  this is your code. you can use `millis()` wherever you want. how are we supposed to know where you want to read your timestamp? I don't understand your problem.

Comment: My problem is that i really don't know where i can put millis because its needed for me to have millis in my code eventhough everything in my code is working properly.If u can tell me where i can add millis wherever you think it will be neceserally i really don't understand millis only delays.So if u can just put millis in a place where you think it would be helpful i will apriciate it .Thank you for the asnwers

Comment: It's not really about some special "place to put millis"  You write an if statement that checks to see how long it has been since the last time something happened and you put that thing to happen inside the if statement.  It doesn't so much matter where you write it as long as the execution of the code keeps getting to that spot over and over to check that if statement.